# Multiple consumers on azure queue

Tags: azure-storage-queues

I have multiple consumers ,running in multiple machines, reading from an azure storage queue. If the first consumer reads the first message from the queue and makes it invisible for 5 minutes then will the second consumer read the next message from the queue or is it blocked ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It will get the next message. If first consumer does not delete/update the first message in 5 minutes, that message will reappear in the queue and one of the consumers will be able to get it again.